# Create Secondary tile without displaying the Pin to Start flyout in windows 8/RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, tiles

I want to create secondary tiles for my application, but all the samples show  `Pin to Start` flyout to user and after user submit, the secondary tile will be created.

I want to create secondary tiles without showing Pin to Start. the scenario, for example, is the user select two or more items and then select create tile for all selected items.

Edit(for more clarification):
 in Weather App, you can pin cities as tiles. my question was about how we can pin items to start together and not one by one. For example you select three cities in weather app and pin all of them.
(I know we can't do it in weather app, I just wonder if it is possible or not and I got my answer)

Comment: This is not even a question. Selected items tile ? What kind of scenario is this. Tiles are meant for apps not items inside app

Comment: @Anobik: I know Tiles are for apps! and this is a question! in Weather Apps, you can pin cities  as tiles. my question was about how we can pin items to start together not one by one. For example you select three cities in weather app and pin all of them . Kraig explains it very well and if I were you, instead of this kind of comment , ask for more details.

Comment: Ok ok sorry dont get angry. Thanks for sharing the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scenario isn't supported. It's by design that every pin to the Start screen is subject to user consent, and at present the API doesn't accommodate multiple pins with one confirmation flyout.

The reason for user consent is to prevent malicious apps from loading up the Start screen wit garbage. It's precious real estate, so the user is always in control.

In Windows 8.1 the consent flyout also allows choice of tile size and alternate images if the app supplies them.

So you'll need to iterate your selection and allow the flyout for each one in turn, that is, be sure to wait until the previous pin is complete before starting the next. Also consider putting an upper limit on the number you can pin at once.